# How to correctly sort by numbers when having numbers higher than 9

Tags: command-line, bash, sort

I have a simple question.

When I have a list of numbers and use sort, I get the following result:

```
10
11
12
7
8
9
```

Because `1` is lower than `7`, it sorts `10` lower than `7`. How can I make it so that it sorts correctly using `10` instead of `1` and then `0`. I need the get the following result:

```
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Thanks!

Edit:
When doing `echo -e "18\n19\n8\n9" | sort -n`, I get the correct output:

```
8
9
18
19
```

But when piping after a find command (`find /home/cas/plex-media/series/ -type f -name "*" ! -name "*.srt" | sort -n`), I don't get the correct ouput:

```
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 18/Pokémon - S18E40 - Balloons, Brionne, and Belligerence!.mp4
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 18/Pokémon - S18E41 - Mounting an Electrifying Charge!.mp4
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 18/Pokémon - S18E42 - Alola, Kanto!.mp4
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 18/Pokémon - S18E43 - When Regions Collide!.mp4
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E01 - Pokémon - I Choose You!.mp4
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E02 - Pokémon Emergency.mp4
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E03 - Ash Catches a Pokémon.mp4
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E04 - Challenge of the Samurai.mp4
```

Comment: You have to use numeric sort `sort -n`

Comment: It worked when doing `echo -e "18\n19\n8\n9" | sort -n`. But when I piped it behind a `find` command, it didn't work

Comment: Think this `sort -t '/' -k5,7V`could work, by first dict sort .../Pokémon/... then version sort .../Pokémon - S01E01... it will group by series